# WSO2 SAML api authentication

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I need to expose an api via WSO2 Api-Manager and I want protect my api not with oAuth2 but via SAML autentication, actually I need to use the APi-Manager as SAML SP.
Therefore I need protect the may api and if a user isn't authenticated on SAML IDP presents the SAML IDP login page.
Is it possible do that with WSO2 Api-Manger or the SAML OSS is releated only for Web SSO for /carbon, /pubblish and /store web app?

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth2 is for authorization. You can use SAML for authentication and use APIM's SAML grant type to get an OAuth2 token using the SAML assertion.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/SAML+Extension+Grant